# How often do viewers upvote an answer?

Tags: discussion, badges, views, popularity

I [had a recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/429150/23834), where the number of upvotes it got were high compared to the views (5/68).

Regardless of whether this was exceptional, I wondered if any analytics had been run on that ratio of a Question's viewer-to-upvotes, and whether anyone had considered if there should be a badge for the rare occurrence when a question is meaningful to a 'more than normal' number of people that visit it.

Pragmatically, I think this would only happen when there are few viewers but many upvote.  Glad to understand if I'm missing facets of this matter.

Comment: Do you mean for questions or answers? There's not really a good way to tell for answers, since ViewCount is a column in the Posts table, and it doesn't have a timestamp associated with it.

Comment: This isn't really about StackOverflow, right? I guess the answer will be very dependent on the site you ask for. I just checked a couple of questions here and a 1/15 ratio seems quite normal here.

Comment: @BDL I thought that SO meta was still the meta for SE generally? Pardon if I'm out of the loop.  Yes I think this could be site-dependent, but I admit to not knowing how badges are supported / codified

Comment: @BilltheLizard I was thinking for Questions.  [updated]